# spring batch Random access in a file to implement binary search

Tags: java, file, spring-batch

I am **implementing a spring batch program**, my scenario is

1. I am having an file called **A** which is having an unique keyfield called RollNumber
2. The rollNumber is in sorted order(ASC)
3. I wanted to get the row which is having rollNumber as:101
4. Is it possible any search algorithm can be implemented on this.
5. I am able to read the file using Itemreader and find the row but the problem is i am having 1 million Record to process,so the time complexity is very high.
   i)Having linear search takes more time,since the file is having large volume of data

Answer (score 0):

Because the records are ordered by key, the natural way of implementing such thing would be [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) but I'm not sure is it possible to do with `Spring Batch`.

The sense of the `Spring Batch` is to read whole file and process it somehow, not to "jump" in file and do some specific stuff. For such operation you should implement your own mechanism (however it can be implemented e.g. in the `Tasklet` instance if this operation must be performed in the scope of the `Spring Batch` process).

The fact is that `FlatFileItemReader` implementation of `ItemReader` includes method

```
public void setLinesToSkip(int linesToSkip) {
    this.linesToSkip = linesToSkip;
}
```

but still - after skipping those line will not allow you to get back or skip another ones during this `Spring Batch` process